# How do I make a picture align under where I placed the code?

Tags: html, css, html-table

When I add an image to a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src...
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

it increases the height of the table, showing the bottom of the image on the line I placed the code:

```
   Cell without             Same cell with image:
    any content:             --------------
                                  Image
                                  Image
    ----------                    Image
                                  Image
    ----------               --------------
```

Look how the bottom of the cell remains the same but the top goes higher.

I want to get the top of the image in the line I placed the code, instead of the bottom showed where I placed the code, like this:

```
----------          --------------
                       Image
----------             Image
                       Image
                       Image 
                    --------------
```

I had a hard trouble trying to explain it, please ask if it's not clear. I know it's something that actually happens a lot, but I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: could we get a link to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only guessing here.

```
td {vertical-align:top;}
```

Not a well defined question. Current and desired outputs look exactly the same and no code sample available.

Comment: It was just that. I'm just starting to write pages sorry for the crappy explanation. Thanks a lot